# Why does the ball in Galileo's double inclined plane experiment reach the same height?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, inertia, galilean-relativity, laws-of-physics, equations-of-motion

Why does the ball in Galileo's double inclined plane experiment reach the same height? I know how to show it by energy conservation law but am unable to prove it by the equations of motion. Can anyone please help me to prove it.

Comment: Use $\mathbf F = m\mathbf a$, and make the dot product both sides with the allowed elementary displacement in the direction of the incline:$\mathbf F\cdot \mathbf {dr} = m\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf {dr}$. You will get the constancy of the sum of what are called kinetic and potential energy.